# Combine Two Internet Connections

Tags: lubuntu

I am using two connection on my laptop one is wired and second is wireless. I would like to know how can i merge both connection bandwidth on my ubuntu 18.04 laptop Without using any other network device like microtik etc....

Comment: You probably does not want to. Multipathing introduces a lot of new problems. You can set up round robin for outgoing connections, but your gain will probably not be worth the hassle.

Comment: May helps you https://superuser.com/questions/660798/merging-two-incoming-broadband-lines-for-faster-internet

Comment: @vidarlo means not possible without using any network device. And is it possible to make load balancing instead of merging the bandwidth ?